# Unit Test Internal Optimization Logic with TDD

Tags: unit-testing

How do you unit test internal optimization logic which doesn't change the public behavior of a class but is complicated enough where you want to make sure it's working?

For example, say I have a class `FooStore` which has `insert(Foo foo)` and `getByProperty(Property)` methods.

If you're doing test driven development, you would first write some failing insertion and retrieval unit tests, then code `FooStore` until the tests pass.

What if you realize later on that you can build some internal data structures in `FooStore` so that insertion or retrieval is much faster. But since there's no change to the behavior of `insert` or `getByProperty`, how would you write a failing unit test first? And how would you write tests that ensure the new logic is actually performing faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do you unit test internal optimization logic which doesn't change the public behavior of a class

By testing the public behavior of the class.

What you're talking about isn't new features, it's refactoring.  Refactoring relies on *existing* tests, not creating new ones.  If you've come up with a better way to develop the code without changing the public behavior then you don't change the tests.  Indeed, the *value* of the tests is so that you can do exactly what you're doing without fear of breaking the public behavior of the class, because you can rely on the tests to validate that behavior.

In the "Red, Green, Refactor" cycle of TDD, you are in the "Refactor" step.

---

You *can* write performance tests, which may use the same technologies as unit tests but from a code organization perspective I would recommend keeping them separate.  Those tests wouldn't validate the functionality, they'd simply measure the performance.  In the "Arrange, Act, Assert" steps of a test, performance tests wouldn't necessarily "Assert" but would rather "Report" the results.  (They may "Assert" that the results meet a minimum threshold, but aside from that there is no real *failure* of a performance test, only a reported *measurement*.)

Comment: It just seems weird that in the Red and Green phases of TDD, there's so much emphasis on writing minimal code to pass unit tests and not writing any code unless there's a failing test to cover it. Then in the Refactor phase, it's pretty much free for all coding as long as the tests still pass.

Comment: @Wei: Well, even when refactoring minimalism is still a good idea.  It wouldn't make much sense to write over-complicated code, TDD or otherwise.